# Optimal insertion to elastic when schema of data may change over time

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to insert data into `elasticsearch`: The data has about 50 different schemas, which will translate to different types in the same `elastic` `index`. One of the types is `UNSTRUCTURED`, but the other schemas are constant and change rarely over time.

The question is: how should I deal with changing schemas over time:

1. Should I validate the schema and if something changes - create a new version and change the `type` to `<<SomeType>>_v1.x`.
2. Just insert the data and let `elastic` analyse and change is't mapping accordingly.

   - Will It successfully create the proper mapping in case the `schama` changes only by addition or detraction of `json` keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if dynamic mapping is enabled , then with each new document having new fields will cause the existing mapping to create the new fields, reference - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html
Also, multiple mapping types within an index have been deprecated since version 5.5 and have been completely removed in version 7.X so you might want to avoid the multi-types approach from the beginning. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html

Be careful with the dynamic mapping though, you can go through the documentation about how ES identifies the data type of each field when doing dynamic mapping , but in certain scenarios you might need to update the mapping manually, because in some cases for example nested objects, ES is not able to distinguish a nested object array from a simple object array, and if you don't mention the field type as nested explicitly while updating the mapping, it would assume its a object array while dynamically updating the mapping.